# How to get Antivirus autoupdate information from system after installing antivirus on mac machine

Tags: macos, antivirus

On my MAC machine i have installed various antiviruses, say Avira, AVG,etc. I wanted to check whether antivirus autoupdate is enabled for antiviruses installed.What i mean by this is if i installed AVAST 8.0 it is getting automatically upgraded to AVAST 9.0, i want to get that information through command line Is there any command or API to get this information from system

Comment: did you found a way to do it??

Comment: Not Yet, I am using free antiviruses(Trail Versions).May be that is the one of the reason why i am not able to see complete information from commandline. Please some one correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: I've seen that some third party SDKs like OPSWAT are capable of doing that. But I don't want to use 3rd party SDKs. Also I checked that AVG has APIs interface to give commands and take information. But adding different set of APIs for different antiviruses will be pain.

Comment: Even that is fine for me to get information using API. As all these are third party antivirues, not originally developed by mac. We cant get common API for fetching information. So please comment some of API's u had found.@bikram990

Comment: just search for AVG API on google it gives some information. I also didn't looked much into that but OPSWAT is using antivirus APIs to perform there task.